# How to run a matlab file in base workspace from gui

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm new in Matlab and I have created a GUI with some push button.

Now, in my current folder I have 4 files:

```
 init.m
 example.mdl (simulink)
 gui.fig
 gui.m
```

In the `gui.fig` I have two push buttons:

1. `Init` button
2. `start_simulink` button

and I would like that when I push on this button the respective action :

1. start init
2. start simulink

but I would like that after pressing a button the `m` file and simulink are performed in a base workspace and not only in a Callback Workspace.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: [`evalin`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want, but with the same result. Finally all variables will be in your base workspace, in my eyes it doesn't matter in this case where your scripts initially got called.

For the initialization I assume you're just loading parameters into the base workspace, so you can use a little function in your callback:

```
function assign2workspace( scriptname )
eval( scriptname );
temp = who;
for iv = 1:length(temp)
    assignin('base',temp{iv},eval(temp{iv}));
end
end
```

where `scriptname` is you initialization script.

---

For Simulink you could to do it analogue (untested though)

```
function startSimulink( modelname )
sim( modelname );

% do what has to be done

temp = who;
for iv = 1:length(temp)
    assignin('base',temp{iv},eval(temp{iv}));
end
end
```

Comment: ok, but I have a m file in my current folder and I would like that pressing a button it runs in a base WS not in callback WS

Comment: I got that, but how does it matter where the m-files got called, when you have all the desired variables in your base workspace afterwards? Thats what my code with `assignin('base',...)` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think my problem was similar to yours. Here's my solution.

Any variable that your script needs from your GUI, be sure to assign it to the base workspace using `assignin('base','variablename')`. In the callback function for your button, run your script using `evalin('base','scriptname')`